# Find partial derivatives when the number of variables is unknown

Tags: function-construction

The idea is that I have a defined function of $n$ variables. I want to find out $n$ and get partial derivation for each of variables,

Suppose you have a function

```
f[w_,x_,y_,z_]: = w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2
```

Is it possible to find partial derivation using - say - 3rd variable (in this case $y$), that is

$\frac{df}{dy} = 2 y$?

Comment: f[w_, x_, y_, z_] := w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2;D[f[w, x, y, z], y]

Comment: @Kuba That's a general idea, but names of the variables and their number is not the same each time.

Comment: Well, if it is a general idea - elaborate more ! Put this way the question is easy enough to answer after browsing the documentation for 5 minutes.

Comment: @Pygmalion The names in case of `Derivative` are not responsible for anything, first part `[0,0,1,0]` is.

Comment: @Kuba OK, but this just transformed one problem to another one.  For i=3 I have to create "Derivative[0,0,1,0][f][x1,x2,x3,x4]"

Comment: @Pygmalion so, what we can assume is give, number of variables or only the fact you want a derivative with respect to 3rd one.

Comment: @Kuba idea is that I have a defined function of $n$ variables.  I want to find out $n$ and get partial derivation for each of variables, $i = 1... n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your comment:

> idea is that I have a defined function of n variables. I want to find out n and get partial derivation for each of variables, i=1...n

I'm sure there must be easier ways to know how many patterns are used to define the function. Also, please consider the following solution as *partial*, since it doesn't account for example for UpValues or multiple definitions.

Anyway:

```
f[w_, x_, y_, z_] := w + x^2 + y^3 + z^4
vars = Length@ Flatten[ReleaseHold[(DownValues@f)[[1, 1]] /. 
               HoldPattern[a__] :> Hold@Verbatim[a] /. 
               HoldPattern -> Sequence /. f -> List] /. Verbatim -> List];
derivs = Derivative[Sequence @@ #][f] & /@ IdentityMatrix[vars];
derivs[[4]][1, 2, 3, 4]
(*
 256
*)
```

Comment: +1. What if `f = ArcTan`?

Comment: +1 `derivs[[3]]` returns `3 #3^2 &` which is generally speaking what I am looking for.  However, would it be possible to change `derivs` in order to return `3 y^2`?

Comment: @Pygmalion Something like `derivs = Derivative[Sequence @@ #][f][w, x, y, z] & /@ 
  IdentityMatrix[vars]` ?

Comment: Kind of.  Maybe I am too demanding, but my idea was to create Mathematica procedure that finds all partial derivatives of an arbitrary function not knowing either number of variables or their names.  In your solution you have to know that names of variables (w,x,y,z).  Quite possibly my problem is unsolvable within Mathamatica

Comment: @Pygmalion The problem is that those aren't "names" but patterns

Comment: Ok, we're talking about pure functions.  Only now I understand the difference between f=x+y and f[x_,y_]=x+y.  A accept the answer.

Comment: @Pygmalion Be sure to understand the differences between `Set` and `SetDelayed`. The concepts underneath are _very_ important

Comment: I understand the difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed`.  But I do not understand the cumulative use of `Apply`, `Seqence` and `Map` in your `derivs` function.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is a polynomial, you can use

```
fd[expr_] := D[expr, #] & /@ Variables[expr]
```

Test:

```
fd[w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2]

Out[] = {2 w, 2 x, 2 y, 2 z}
```

Or a slightly longer version with better looking output:

```
fd[expr_] := (With[{x = #}, HoldForm[D[expr, x]]] -> D[expr, #]) & /@ Variables[expr]

fd[w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2]
```