# Creating a function as a table of derivations

Tags: functions

Suppose I have function, which is in fact a list of $n$ functions with $n$ parameters

```
f = {#1 + #2^2 + #3^3, #1^2 + #2^3 + #3^4, #1^3 + #2^4 + #3^5}&
```

I want to get a function that is in fact matrix of all possible partial derivations

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_3} \end{array} \right)$
, i.e

```
g = {{1,2#1,3#1^2},{2#2,3#2^2,4#2^3},{3#3^2,4#3^3,5#3^4}}&
```

I tried to do that myself by adapting the answer [Find partial derivatives when the number of variables is unknown](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41184/find-partial-derivatives-when-the-number-of-variables-is-unknown), but I don't understand the cumulative use of `Apply`, `Seqence` and `Map`.

Comment: Do you also need to determine the number of parameters, or is that known?

Comment: @Ian number of parameters is equal to number of functions and should be determined too.  Too bad, `Length` and `Dimensions` don't work on `f` as defined above!

Comment: Sure they do, but the `Head` of `f` is "Function" not list. Try `Dimensions[f[[1]]]`.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

One can first find all arguments as slots and then differentiate with respect to them:

```
    f = {#1 + #2^2 + #3^3, #1^2 + #2^3 + #3^4, #1^3 + #2^4 + #3^5} &;
    args = ToExpression@Union@StringCases[ToString@FullForm@f,
        RegularExpression["Slot\\[\\d+\\]"]];
    g = Function[D[f@@args,#]&/@args//Evaluate]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you have missed the point.  I need function that is in fact matrix.  E.g., to be able to write `deriv=D[f @@ args, #] & /@ args` and then use `deriv[1,2,3]`

Comment: @Pygmalion One can use `Function` to get a function out of it. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake, in fact I need the transposed matrix of the above. Can you make an adjustment to your solution?

Comment: @Pygmalion   `g = Function[D[f@@args,#]&/@args//Transpose//Evaluate]`

Answer (score 2):

The derivative function is actually quite general. For example, say you have a list of three functions in three variables. Then the function `D` can calculate the matrix of derivatives directly:

```
f[x_] := {x[[1]] + x[[2]]^2 + x[[3]] x[[2]], x[[1]] x[[2]], x[[3]]^3};
z = Array[x, 3];
D[f[z], {z}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `der=D[f[z], {z}]` is not function of vector x, i.e. `der[{a,b,c}]` does not work.

Comment: With `der = D[f[z], {z}]; der /. {x[1] -> a, x[2] -> b, x[3] -> c}` gives the form you ask for.

Comment: +1 Thanks.  Another solution, but the previous one is tidier, as I can directly pass vector (of variable Length)

Answer (score 1):

```
mf = Derivative[Sequence @@ #][f] & /@ IdentityMatrix@Length@f[[1]]
(*
  {{1, 2 #1, 3 #1^2} &, {2 #2, 3 #2^2, 4 #2^3} &, {3 #3^2, 4 #3^3, 5 #3^4} &}
*)
 mf /. Function[o___] :> o /. x_ :> Function[x]
(*
 {{1, 2 #1, 3 #1^2}, {2 #2, 3 #2^2, 4 #2^3}, {3 #3^2, 4 #3^3, 5 #3^4}} &
*)
```

Comment: Hi again!  This creates vector of three vectorial functions, what I need is matrix function (& in the end)

Comment: @Pygmalion Take a look now

Comment: Yes, not it works!  I am amazed how two so different procedures have the same effect.  Hopefully I will understand them sometime in future!